# How can ImageView link to a email?

Tags: android

Is it possible to make an imageview link to the email app? Like when you click it the email app will open with a specific email address to send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
findViewById(R.id.imageview).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View _) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.fromParts("mailto","abc@gmail.com", null));
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
img.setOnClickListener(
    new OnClickListener(View v) {
        String yourMail = "mail@example.com";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{yourMail});
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your content");
        try {
            startActivity(intent, "Pick an email application...");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(YourMainActivity.this, "Have no email application!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
);
```